# Convert strings to numbers in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
MyArray = [ 
["Oswaldo","21749"],
["Mao","19580"],
["Angeline",'53692']
]
```

How do I convert the numbers from strings to actual numbers and save in the same array or in the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `+` to cast strings to numbers:

```
for (var i in myArray) {
    myArray[i][1] = +myArray[i][1];
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shu03nbe/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is more efficient and elegant:

```js
var MyArray = [ 
["Oswaldo","21749"],
["Mao","19580"],
["Angeline",'53692']
];

MyArray = MyArray.map(function (obj) {
    return [obj[0],parseInt(obj[1])];
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(MyArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, `js` attempts *not* referencing an `index` , for instance where position of array item string containing only numbers may *not* be at index `1` within an array contained within `MyArray`

Try

```js
var MyArray = [
  ["Oswaldo", "21749"],
  ["Mao", "19580"],
  ["Angeline", '53692']
];

MyArray = MyArray.map(function(items) {
  return items.map(function(item) {
    return /^\d+$/.test(item) && !/[a-z]/i.test(item) ? Number(item) : item
  })
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(MyArray));
```

Comment: We answer at the same time, but you can achieve that with just one map. Watch my answer..

Comment: @DrKey See updated post.  `js` attempts to _not_ reference at specific `index` within array within `MyArray` , for instance where array item containing numbers may _not_ be at index `1` within array within `MyArray`

Comment: Of course my function will works only if array within MyArray contains 2 values with original index. Your function works even if that array contains more than two values at random indexes. Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

Recursive iteration will let you iterate nested array, then just coherce the value to Number

```
function parseNum(arr) {

    arr.forEach(function(value, index) {
        if ( Array.isArray(value) ) {
            parseNum(value);
        } else if ( !isNaN(parseFloat(value)) ) {
            arr[index] = (+value);
        }
    });

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/33g6qq8u/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Bladepianist/rpy2aedh/1/

```
MyArray = [ 
["Oswaldo","21749"],
["Mao","19580"],
["Angeline",'53692']
];

for (var item in MyArray) {
    MyArray[item][1] = parseInt(item[1], 10);
}
```

parseInt() if you want them in int and the "10" is for base 10.
parseFloat() if you'd prefer them in that format :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < MyArray.length; ++i) {
    MyArray[i][1] = parseInt(MyArray[i][1]);
    // Or parseFloat if there is a float
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com)

```js
var MyArray = [ 
["Oswaldo","21749"],
["Mao","19580"],
["Angeline",'53692']
];

var result = jinqJs().from(MyArray).select(function(row){row[1] = Number(row[1]); return row;});
document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre><br><br>';
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/fordth/jinqJs/master/jinqjs.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes to the previous example

```
var MyArray = [ 
   [0, "Oswaldo","21749"],
   [1, "Mao","19580"],
   [2, "Angeline",'53692']
];

function buscar() {
  var result = new jinqJs().from(MyArray).where(function(row){return (row[0] == '1')}).select(function(row){return row[1]});
  console.log(result);
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3VXwxRSnybt9qBYaLDPk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Two variations provided below:

The first for changing a specific index in a 2D array to numbers, as per the OP.

The second for converting every element of an array of number strings to numbers, which is the answer I was looking for when I found this page.

```js
const stringArr = [ 
    ["Oswaldo","21749"],
    ["Mao","19580"],
    ["Angeline","53692"]
  ];

stringArr.forEach((el,i,arr) => arr[i][1] = +el[1]); // convert every index[1] of 2D array to number

console.log(stringArr);

const numStringArr = [ 
    ["31749","21749"],
    ["29580","19580"],
    ["63692","53692"]
  ];

numStringArr.forEach((el,i,arr) => arr[i] = el.map(e => +e)); // convert every element of 2D array to number

console.log(numStringArr);
```